# Error while inserting contentdocumentlink with Collaborator access through Apex

Tags: files, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I have a lightning component which executes an apex class on load. In apex class, I'm getting some list of files and providing 'Collaborator' access to the logged-in user if he is eligible. When I'm inserting a single contentdocumentlink with shareType='c' it works but doesn't if the same record is in the List.

Error : System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, Invalid sharing type C: [ShareType]

Code :

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static void createContentDocLink(String recordId){
        Set<Id> documentIds = new Set<Id>(); 
        List<ContentDocumentLink> cdl=[SELECT id,LinkedEntityId,ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN:recordId];  
        for(ContentDocumentLink cdLink:cdl){  
            documentIds.add(cdLink.ContentDocumentId);  
        }    
        List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlList = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();

            for(ID id : documentIds){
                ContentDocumentLink cd = new ContentDocumentLink();
                cd.ContentDocumentId = id;
                System.debug('cd.ContentDocumentId :'+id);
                cd.LinkedEntityId = Userinfo.getUserId();
                System.debug('Userinfo.getUserId() :'+Userinfo.getUserId());
                cd.ShareType = 'C';
                cd.Visibility = 'InternalUsers';
                cdlList.add(cd);
                system.debug('cdlList :'+cdlList);
                insert cdlList; 
                //Below commneted code works
            /*  ContentDocumentLink cd = new ContentDocumentLink();
                cd.ContentDocumentId = '06**************';
                cd.LinkedEntityId = '005***********';
                cd.ShareType = 'C';
                system.debug('cD '+cd);
                insert cd;*/
        }

    }
```

Note : getting the same error even though the list contains single record.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure User has permission to the library. Please read the description of [ShareType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) field

[image]

Comment: Hi, Please see the code I've posted. It is working if im not using a List

Answer (score 0):

INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, Invalid sharing type C: [ShareType] generally occurs when you are trying to share a file to a user who already have Collaborator permission. The user can explicitly view and edit the shared file.

Before inserting the contentdocumentlink, you need to check whether the file has been shared already with the user or not.

As a workaround, You need to create one more separate set of contentdocumentid to check if the user already having the access to that file.

```
Set<Id> documentIdsForUsr = new Set<Id>(); 
        List<ContentDocumentLink> cdl=[SELECT id,LinkedEntityId,ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =:userinfo.getuserid()];  
        for(ContentDocumentLink cdLink:cdl){  
            documentIdsForUsr.add(cdLink.ContentDocumentId);  
        } 


for(ID id : documentIds){
            if(!documentIdsForUsr.contains(id){                 
                ContentDocumentLink cd = new ContentDocumentLink();
                cd.ContentDocumentId = id;
                cd.LinkedEntityId = Userinfo.getUserId();
                cd.ShareType = 'C';
                cd.Visibility = 'InternalUsers';
                cdlList.add(cd); 
            }
```